# Simple search program using arrays help me

Tags: arrays, function, search

When the user types in a word the program is searching for a match in an array, if there is a match the program prints out the string from the array.The code below does just that. My goal is to make it so when a word matches with a a word in the array the program should print an info not only the word. I thought I can fill the array with functions, but its not working. Is it even possible ?

I am using league of legend hero names because they are a lot and I know them and it doesent take me a lot of time to think of names that way :D

The idea is if the user types  in voly, the program finds voly in the array and prints out(for example) his starting life, armor, mr and so on.

I tryed a lot of thing with functions but I cant make it work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
string voly(string holder,string heroName);

int main(){

    const int numH = 10;
    string holder;
    string heroName;
    string heroList[numH] = {"voly", "teemo", "vladimir", "morgana", "jax", "ekko", "anivia", "nunu", "ashe", "tresh" };


    cout << "Enter hero name.\n" << endl;
    cin >> heroName;

    for (int i = 0; i < numH; i++){
        holder = heroList[i];
        if (heroName == holder){
            cout << holder << endl;
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

string voly(string holder, string heroName) {
        cout << "Voly is the best" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to learn about structs. You can utilize them to encapsulate all hero information in a hero struct, as follows. This serves as kind of a prototype for each hero:

`struct hero { 
    string name; 
    int hp; 
    int mana; 
    float mreg; 
    ... 
    void printMe() { cout << 'hp: ' << hp << endl << 'mana: ' << mana << endl << ...; }
}`

Using the printMe() function of that specific hero object, you can print its values.

Then, for each hero, create a struct object and add them to the array.

`hero* pointer = new hero[numH];
pointer[0] = new hero {
    name: "voly",
    hp: 150
};
pointer[1] = new hero {
    ...
};`

(Try considering some import function via a .CSV file or so.)

By using your for loop, compare the name:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numH; i++){
    if (heroName == pointer[i].name){
        pointer[i]->printMe();
    }
}
```

Try using Google to find tutorials on that. Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure about the syntax in C++, maybe someone can help me out.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you. I will do some research, watch some tutorials and try to do it with data structures. I am just learning the language and I was avoiding to even thing about data structures and teh advanced stuff becasue im stil a noob :D

Comment: Yes, I understand :) I only find it a bit problematic here because there's so much data you work with. You should always try to automate as much as you can when it comes to data reading / importing. Following a clear scheme is helping here (such as defining a struct / class).